# What is analogous to the set of four main diagonals in Rotational Symmetry of Cube, if we want to find the total symmetry of cube?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, platonic-solids

I am working on a project on applications of group theory, starting from point groups and molecular symmetry.
Coming up on representations of each point groups, I started studying Representations of Finite Group. Also, I am reading upon Platonic Solids.
For a cube, I determined the elements of the Rotational Symmetry group, of order 24. The elements of this group is a permutation of the four main diagonals of the cube. So, is the set of four diagonals representation of the cube? Can we use these four diagonals to find the elements of the total symmetry group of the cube?
Applying Symmetry on Platonic solids to study its structure is okay, but what exactly does it tell us? Can it be extended to understand the nature and properties of something else? What is the essence of this study?

I need some good references for symmetric groups of Platonic solids. I want to do some problem solving (self - research) on this related topic. It can be computational, theoretical or simulation. But I am unable to determine the proper link between Platonic Solids and Group Theory( or rather can't find a problem statement).

Comment: Symmetry groups of platonic solids are pretty well understood and have been written about before. What do you find unsatisfactory about eg [this](https://www.math.brown.edu/reschwar/MFS/handout3.pdf), [this](https://people.math.wisc.edu/~sgurevich/RT-P1-Solutions.pdf), [this](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~or257/teaching/IAGroups/2019/groups.pdf)? You can't find the full isometry group of a cube by acting on the diagonals as it's too big. You could act on the set of all vertices, or the diagonals union $S = \{-1, 1\}$, where the action on $S$ is given by multiplication by the determinant.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen can we label the 8 corners as {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}? then the permutation matrix will be of order 8x8? is that correct? Or should I use vertices as (x,y,z) co-ordinates?

Comment: Yes, you can use whatever eight labels you like for the vertices to find a subgroup of the symmetric group on $8$ elements isomorphic to the symmetry group of the cube (aka "a faithful permutation representation"). Now I'm not quite sure if you're interested in permutation representations or linear representations (ie sets of matrices) - there is indeed also a faithful three-dimensional linear representation over $\Bbb R$ of the symmetry group of the cube - basically because the symmetries are all isometries of Euclidean space fixing the centre of the cube.